# Is "vice versa" redundant with "one [verb] the other"?

Tags: meaning

I feel that "one [verb] the other" also includes the "other [verb] the one" meaning, but I am not sure.

Consider this sentence:

> The design and development process shall run in parallel, one informing the other and vice versa.

Is it clear that **design is informing development** and **development is informing design**, even without the 'vice versa'?

Comment: How can a single process inform _the other_? // I'd say that with A and B, 'the one informing the other' defaults to 'A informs B _and_ B informs A'. 'Each informing the other' is crystal clear and Latinesque-free.

Comment: ++1 'Each informing the other'

Comment: *The design and development* ***processes***?